# How to fix links breaking out of line in responsive mode?

Tags: html, css, shopify

On my custom shopify site when the main menu is in responsive mode, the links get all wonky and out of line, but only in a short area that seems to be random depending on browser.

*Here is how they are supposed to look:*

[image]

*Here is how they look when they are breaking:*

[image]

According to all of the responsive code, they are set up all the same.

Here is the code:

```css
li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 10px !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}
li ul li:first-child {
  display: none !important;
}
li ul li {
  font-size: 13px !important;
  clear: left !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<li class="site-nav--has-dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
  <a href="/pages/studios" class="site-nav__link">
             STUDIOS
             <span class="icon icon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         </a>
  <ul class="site-nav__dropdown">
    <div>
      <li>
        <a href="/pages/studios" class="site-nav__link ">STUDIOS</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/pages/locations" class="site-nav__link ">LOCATIONS</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/pages/class-schedule" class="site-nav__link ">UPCOMING CLASSES</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://yogavida-dev.myshopify.com/pages/studios#schedule" class="site-nav__link ">EVENTS</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <span class="arrow">&nbsp;</span>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Please share your webpage link to better understand the issue, the code you have provided does not include complete css

Comment: Please do *not* share your webpage link.  Provide complete code necessary to reproduce the problem as part of the question. [mcve]

Comment: it would seem that the code you have provided is not the code required - the link text for the shown options does not match the link text in the code provided.

Comment: Note that you are using nested uls so may have a conflict with other css for them and also the use of !important should be discouraged !IMPORTANT;